# Cannot see from code behind the values of Dynamically created textboxes using AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS programming. Any help would be highly appreciated.

1. A HTML text box will be created each time a HTML button is clicked.
2. In *webform1.aspx* submit button click even cannot capture the values entered in those text boxes.

I used `request.form`, loop through controls in the `form1` but cannot find dynamically created controls.

How to post and see the data entered in those textboxes from code behind?

Please find the code below:

**webform1.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="`server">
         <div>
         <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <li ng-repeat="element in elements ">
               <input type="text" ng-model="element.id" runat=server/>
            </li>
            <input type="button" value="+" ng-click="newItem()" />
         </div>
      </form>
   </body>
   <script language="JavaScript">
      var app = angular. Module('myApp', []);
      app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
          var counter = 0;     
          $scope.elements = [{ id: counter, value: ''}];

          $scope.newItem = function () {
              if ($scope.elements[counter].value != '') {
                   counter++;
                   var str1 = 'txtdynamic';
                   str1 += counter;
                   $scope.elements.push({ id: str1, value: '' });
              }
          }
      });
   </script>
</html>
```

**webform1.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get the html ng repeat textbox control values
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `$http.post()`?

Comment: No I did not.I have to check how to do that.

Comment: scope.elements doesn't retain values to post,I tried the following code

Comment: $scope.ButtonClick = function () {

            var post = $http({

                method: "POST",

                url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",

                dataType: 'json',

                data: { name: $scope.elements[0].value },

                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }

            });

Comment: Why is my scope .elements array not holding any values?? can some on e  help??

Comment: Hi lin,can you help me with one more thing,   I wanted to create a file with the entries -  values entered into the dynamic  textboxes. can I add a eventhandler to the html button to call server side button.

Comment: Just ask a new question. We gonna help you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it the right way my friend. Compare the following codes with your approach.

**> [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqbfr79b/)**.

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <form id="form1" runat="`server">
    <div>
      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <li ng-repeat="element in elements">
          <input type="text" ng-model="elements[element.id].value" runat=server/>
        </li>
        <input type="button" value="+" ng-click="newItem()" />
        <input type="button" value="send" ng-click="ButtonClick()" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    var counter = 0;

    $scope.elements = [{
      id: counter,
      value: ''
    }];

    $scope.newItem = function() {
      if ($scope.elements[counter].value != '') {
        counter++;
        var str1 = 'txtdynamic';
        str1 += counter;
        $scope.elements.push({
          id: str1,
          value: ''
        });
      }
    }

    $scope.ButtonClick = function() {
      var post = $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          id: angular.isDefined($scope.elements[0]) ? $scope.elements[0].value : null
        },
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but Adding textboxes dynamically is failing if I modified as u said.

Comment: this is working fine after I modified       ng-model="elements[element.id].value"   as  ng-model="element.value"